# Java Iterating an object of custom class

Tags: java

I have no idea about iterating an object in java, however I've tried to create a custom class and try to get a result from it but I got a same iteration result whereas the data set into object are different.
and here are my class.

```
package property;

import java.util.ArrayList;
public class obj_error {

    public Integer error_code;
    public String error_desc;
    public Integer error_line;
    public String error_modul;
    public Integer total = 0;
    public ArrayList<obj_error> list = new ArrayList<obj_error>();

    public void set(Integer code, String desc, String module,Integer line ){
        this.error_code = code;
        this.error_desc = desc;
        this.error_modul= module;
        this.error_line = line;
        this.total      = total+1;
        //list.add(this);
        set_list();
    }

    public Integer error_code()     { return error_code; }
    public String error_desc()      { return error_desc; }
    public Integer error_line()     { return error_line; }
    public String error_modul()     { return error_modul; }
    public Integer total()          { return total; }
    public ArrayList<obj_error> get_error_list() { return list; }

    public void set_code(Integer param)  { this.error_code = param; }
    public void set_desc(String param)   { this.error_desc = param; }
    public void set_line(Integer param)  { this.error_line = param; }
    public void set_modul(String param)    { this.error_modul = param; }
    public void set_total(Integer param)   { this.total = total+1; }
    public void set_list(){ list.add(this); }


}
```

and this is where I call that class

```
package testcase;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import property.obj_error;

public class set_error {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        obj_error error = new obj_error();
        error.set(1001,"Not Valid","Loand",1);
        error.set(1002,"Not Validsafasd","Loan",2);
        System.out.println(error.list);


        for(Iterator<obj_error> i = error.get_error_list().iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
          obj_error item = i.next();
          System.out.println(item.error_code+" " + item.error_desc+ " " +item.error_line+ " " + item.error_modul);

        }
        //print out result
        //1002 Not Validsafasd 2 Loan
        //1002 Not Validsafasd 2 Loan


    }
}
```

Comment: not answering your question, but this looks like it should be `private` `public void set_list(){ list.add(this); }`

Comment: have a look at your list member and read about static vs. nonstatic  class members

Comment: @Gernot static members *are* class members.

Comment: first read about iterator, only then you will understand, try basic googling

Comment: First of all, please respect the Java naming conventions. Second: you're creating a single object, modify it and add it to a list it itself contains several times. So this list ends up containing several references to this unique object, and the state of this unique object is the state after the last modification you made to it. Move the list out of the object, create one object per error, and add each of these objects to the list.

Comment: @Scary : it doesn't change anything

Comment: @Gernot, Flying Zombie and JB Nizet : Thanks for your reference,,

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a case of frankendesign. You're using a single instance of your `obj_error` (which you should probably rename to `ObjError` to make it easier on Java eyes to read), when you really seem to want 2 instances.

You should take the `list` out of your `obj_error` class and put it in your main method instead. If you convert your `set` method into a constructor, the design starts to look a lot better (artist's rendering):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<obj_error> list = new ArrayList<obj_error>();

    obj_error error1 = new obj_error(1001, "Not Valid", "Loand", 1);
    list.add(error1);

    obj_error error2 = new obj_error(1002, "Not Validsafasd", "Loan", 2);
    list.add(error2);

    System.out.println(list);

    for(obj_error item : list)
        System.out.println(item.error_code+" " + item.error_desc+ " " +item.error_line+ " " + item.error_modul);
```

Comment: Don't put code in comments. I'm sure you can see why.

Comment: You can edit your post to add the changes you've made, and if there are still issues.

Answer (score 0):

There is so much to say... First, applause that it compiles.

As tip, you should use different classes for the main object that contain the list of errors from the objects in this list. Currently, you are dealing with a sort of tree structure.

For example:

```
class ErrorContainer{
     // ...
     private List<ErrorMsg> = new ArrayList<>;
     // ...  continue
```

It should be clearer.